# Flash - Flash Media Server Alternative

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

I am not advanced yet, but i know what exactly i am looking for and want to do. After doing Air/Flex i came to a stage i need "Flash Media Server Xversion"

Question: Is there any Open/Free Linux based alternative for this "Flash Media Server"? 
By google i came to this, is it also possible to use as alternative 
1. http://osflash.org/red5
or
2. http://www.red5server.org/

?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Red5 can be seen as an FMS alternative. It is written entirely in Java and it works in Linux. However, not all the features from FMS exists in Red5.

Comment: thank you, its working http://i.imgur.com/3A581.png but can i use this to make peer to peer voice/video also?

Comment: From what I know RTMFP is supported only on FMS.
Take a look also on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_apps_stratus_lccs.html , maybe it can help you

Comment: Thank you and Never mind, just a side question. i see now FMS vs Red5 vs Xyz in details, The reason of not using FMS for most people would be the price and linux platform compatibility. FMS work in linux? Is it license for year method or is it one time based payment? I would say then FMS is the best of best, the rest is just incubator media server's.

Comment: FMS is installed as a trial, works great in linux, here screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/iVaDL.png